# Multi-language receipt Doesn't Printing with Star Micronics Printer in Android

Tags: android, printing

**I am tried with all CodePageType and CharSet to print Arabic, Japanese etc language but it's printing some symbols on receipt. For English it's working fine with desired format. I also followed official pdf and methods like appendInternationalCode() etc but not working.**
[image]

Star Micronics (SM230I) Printer

StarPRNTSDK Android Sdk

Android API 26 to 29

Tried UTF-8, Shift-JIS, JIS, ASCII etc.

Tried following CodePageType

```
    //Some method calling......  

  Charset encoding;
  StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
  ArrayList<CodePageType> codeList=new ArrayList<>();
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP437);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP737);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP772);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP774);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP851);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP852);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP855);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP857);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP858);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP860);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP861);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP862);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP863);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP864);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP865);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP866);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP869);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP874);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP928);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP932);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP998);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP999);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP1001);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP1250);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP1251);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP1252);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP2001);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3001);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3002);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3011);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3012);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3021);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3041);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3840);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3841);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3843);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3844);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3845);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3846);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3847);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.CP3848);
  codeList.add(CodePageType.UTF8);

  //encoding = Charset.forName("JIS");
  encoding=Charset.forName("Shift-JIS");
  //encoding = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  //encoding = Charset.forName("ASCII");

  for(CodePageType pageType:codeList)
  {
     builder.appendCodePage(pageType);
     stringBuffer.append("عنوان"+" = "+encoding+" = "+pageType);
     stringBuffer.append("\n");
  }
  builder.append(stringBuffer.toString().getBytes(encoding));

//print receipt ....
```

**I need to print in multi-language like Arabic, Japanese, Chinese, Dutch etc for now it's working only for English and for all other printing symbols.TIA**

Answer (score 0):

```
IDisplayCommandBuilder builder1 = StarIoExt.createDisplayCommandBuilder(StarIoExt.DisplayModel.SCD222);
builder1.appendCodePage(IDisplayCommandBuilder.CodePageType.Japanese);
builder1.append("eewrdew こんにちは".getBytes(Charset.forName("Shift-JIS")));
builder1.appendCodePage(IDisplayCommandBuilder.CodePageType.Japanese);
builder1.append("eewrdew こんにちは".getBytes(Charset.forName("JIS")));
builder1.getPassThroughCommands();
```

I have even tried this but didn't find any solution till yet.

Comment: Also tried above and createScaleCommandBuilder but facing same issue.